# Debug Android library project with java source code

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I followed the following tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

and I have 2 projects : the starter project and the library project. Most of the source code is located into the library project

When I debug the android application and when I place a breakpoint into the java, the breakpoint work but it jump in the class file located in Library project folder (of the starter project).

I would like to stop in the java code, so I don't have to switch between the source and the compiled code and so modify the source. Is it possible ?

regards

Comment: AFAIK it isn't possible, because auf the view switch between the android and the java perspective. Even though you assign the right sources to the library, i doesn't work. Anyway, I also would like to know if there is a solution to that...

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:
(After having clicked debug at least once before)

- Open the debug view in eclipse (use the menu at the top: Window -> Show View -> Debug)
- Right click one of the activities in the debug window "Edit source lookup"
- Click "Add"
- Select "Java Project"
- Check the box for the Android Library project
- Press OK

Comment: I know that "Thanks! Me too!" comments are frowned upon, but this answer surely deserves a "Thanks! Me too!". So... um, thanks. And me too. :)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the solution was:

- Open the debug view in eclipse (use the menu at the top: Window -> Show View -> Debug)
- Right click one of the activities in the debug window "Edit source lookup"
- Check the "Search for duplicate source files on the path"

jhnclvr's aswer lead me to this dialog