# android project break point hitting in the class file instead of source code file

Tags: java, android, debugging

I have two android projects one library project (A) and the second one an android project (B) which is referencing the android library project A.

Both projects are in the workspace ..

When I am debugging the application project B and drill down into the library code of project A. Eclipse takes me to the class file instead of the .java file.

This is quite annoying, causing quite a few redundant files opening up,..

If the code is there in the workspace, I expect breakpoints etc to hit in java files and not in the .class files.

Please any ideas ?

Thank you, 
Ahmed

Comment: Is project B recognized in project A as an Eclipse project, or do you use a jar file of project B?

Comment: I am doing it via project properties ->android -> library -> ADD and then select the library project. As a result there is a node for libraries created which does reference mylibrary.jar file.

Comment: Ok, so on the jar file in your library container, you should be able to right-click it and select properties. In Java source attachement you can reach your Project B source path. This is not ideal but it should work. I have never used Android SDK so can't help you more on this.

Comment: I just looked into jar properties and there was already a reference to source code of library there :|

Comment: make sure that reference points to the library project's source folder, not the bin / class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug Android library project with java source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403634/debug-android-library-project-with-java-source-code)

Comment: I had similar problem and [opening class files from debug view][1] helped to me 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441498/opening-source-code-from-debug-view-edits-class-after-android-r18-update