# Eclipse prevents editing after debug mode entered

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm working on an Android project in Eclipse. I just updated to:

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Since then, if I hit a breakpoint in debug, I can no longer type in any files. The keyboard seems to work for stepping through code and for typing text elsewhere in Eclipse outside the file editors. The behavior persists even if I terminate the debug session. (I'm debugging on a device.)

I need to restart Eclipse in order to be able to change files in the editor. Not too fun! I've not found any recent bug that explains the behavior. FWIW the upgrade wiped out my preferences too. It looks like my install history was lost too because the previous configuration does not seem available to revert to.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Also of interest: if I close a file and reopen in the same Eclipse session, I can then edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you're debugging `.class` files instead of their correspodning `.java` files. This happens a lot when library projects are involved. Some other things happen too -- you can place double breakpoints, &c. It's a bit annoying.

You can normally fix this issue by editing the *Source Lookup* when debugging. Please see the answer to this question: [Debug Android library project with java source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403634/debug-android-library-project-with-java-source-code)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice it was the class files coming up, not java.